# php: using batching for google cloud storage delete operations

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set up batch deleting of GoogleCloudStorage objects. After

```
$config = [
            'projectId' => <MY Project ID>
            'keyFile'  => json_decode(file_get_contents( <my json key file> ), true)
          ];
$google_client = new Google_Client($config);
$google_client->setUseBatch(true);

$delete_batch_storage_client = new Google_Service_Storage($google_client);

$delete_batch = new Google_Http_Batch($google_client, false, NULL, "batch/storage");


$storage_client = new StorageClient($config);
$bucket = $storage_client->bucket(<my bucket name>);

$params = [
    'prefix' => <my image path>,
    'fields' => 'items/name, items/size, items/updated'
];

foreach ( $bucket->objects($params) as $object )
{
    $delete_batch->add($delete_batch_storage_client->objects->delete($bucket->name(), $object->name()));
}

$result = $delete_batch->execute();
```

But when running my script, it builds the request, runs it, and fails. Best as I can see,
the problem is here:

```
"message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.delete access to the Google Cloud Storage object."
```

But, examining the source code for the Google_Http_Batch object execute() function, there is no authentication header created. What did I miss in my setup? I would have thought that instantiating the Google_Http_Batch object with the Google_Client would supply that info? But apparently not.

per note from John Hanley below, going to the console and looking at my service account, it looks like it has the following roles:

```
Editor
Firebase Service Management Service Agent
Owner
Service Account Token Creator
Service Account User
Viewer
```

I would have thought that either Editor or Owner would have delete permission.

I have only one explicit USE command in the code:

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

Here are the versions for the google libraries currently on my system:

google/apiclient                  v2.4.1
google/apiclient-services         v0.132
google/auth                       v1.8.0
google/cloud-core                 v1.39.0
google/cloud-storage              v1.23.0PHP
google/common-protos              1.3.1
google/crc32                      v0.1.0
google/grpc-gcp                   0.1.5
google/protobuf                   v3.17.3
grpc/grpc                         1.30.0
guzzlehttp/guzzle                 6.5.3
guzzlehttp/promises               v1.3.1
guzzlehttp/psr7                   1.6.1
psr/cache                         1.0.1
psr/http-message                  1.0.1
psr/log                           1.1.3

I looked at the content of the batch, and it seems that there ought to be either authorization header(s) on each delete request, or (I think better) one at the top level, and they aren't there. So I'm not doing something right when instantiating the objects.

Comment: The service account that you are using does not have the permission **storage.objects.delete**. Edit your question and list the roles the service account has.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense to me - the error message say "anonymous caller", which says to me that the request is going up with no authentication, not that my service account doesn't have the role. Or is the PHP library deep inside saying "i'm not going to put any authentication in because this service account doesn't have access to the delete function"?  Trying to figure out how to tell what roles my service account has.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word **anonymous** in the error. That means no authorization credentials. To figure out the roles, go to the Google Cloud Console -> IAM. Include details on the libraries with versions that you are using **composer show** and the **use** lines from you code.